# How does a rails resource know to use the show view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking at this tutorial: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up

We get on to rails resources.

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root             'static_pages#home'
  get 'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup'  => 'users#new'
  resources :users
end
```

**app/controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
  end
end
```

**app/views/users/show.html.erb**

```
<%= @user.name %>, <%= @user.email %>
```

There is also this handy table of telling us how ruby will handle the various requests to the `Users` resource.

[image]

I have two questions here.

1. How does RoR know when accessing the `/users`, `/users/1` etc urls, what to actually use the `index`, `show` methods.
2. More importantly, - when the `show` method is called, how it does it know the give the `show.html.erb` view to browser? What if I wanted to return a different view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mechanism that is responsible for dispatching actions in response to requests is **router**. You define all the routes in `config/routes.rb` file as you said. Each line in this files define the request in clear way. `resources` is a shorthand to define a set of routes - all of them [listed here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).

There are two thins that distinct requests - the URL and the HTTP request type (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE). Based on these two things you can clearly direct the request to proper controller. Take a look on this one:

```
get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'
```

This means: If you get a request of type `get` directed to url of value `/help` dispatch the request to controller `static_pages` and its action `help`. What happens in `help` action is a matter of code.

This is also an answer to your second question, how does Rails know what template should it render. Assume that we still work on above example of `help` action. If this action has no explicit `render` call, Rails will use its convention over configuration and search for a template that will be in directory called as the controller and in file name as the action name. Therefore, it will render the file that is in `app/views/static_pages/help.html.erb`. On the other hand, the developer can call `render` with explicit other file name, e.g.: `render "products/show"`.

If you want to find more please take a look at these two Rails guides:

- [Layouts and rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render)
- [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 3):

**1.** Rails knows which methods to use based on the HTTP request type (GET, POST, PUT, or DELETE) and the endpoint. So when you hit the `'/users'` endpoint with a GET request, it will use the index method. When you hit the `'/users/:id'` endpoint with a GET request, it will use the show method.

**2.** The `show.html.erb` view is used because the name matches the show method. To use a different view, just use `match` in the routes file like so:

```
match "users" => "users#show"
```

The example above would match the `'/users'` route to the `'/user/:id'` route.

Comment: Just wanted to add that `match` means that all HTTP verbs will hit it equally, so in this case even a POST would go to UsersController#show. If you need different functionality Rails also has `get` `post`, etc. that you can use instead of `match` (or if you want a few to match but not all you can use `match "users" => "users#show", via: [:get, :post]` [More info](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html)

Comment: What's say you wanted to dynamically assign the route depending on the kind of user it was?

Comment: @dwjohnston You should see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230130/rails-routes-based-on-condition). The users first go to a home route which has a case statement and depending on the user type, the application will render a specific view.

Comment: @Mario yes you are correct. Thank you for the additional info!

Answer (score 0):

rails is said to have convention over configuaration. this is one of the strongest feature available in Rails.in another way. Smart and less code. Here when u say method name as show. rails by default will look for show.html.erb. if you want to explicitly render some other view. You can do this in your controller methods

> render :new_view_name

Regarding the routes.

> resources :users

This is very helpful when we have Rest calls ,crud operations.it creates 7 urls for crud. And how it differentiate is depending on http data type.