# How to replace routes for user model by role

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have model User contain column role.

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :address
      t.integer :role
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

role is shop if User.role = 1 , role is shipper User.role = 0

Routes.rb

```
resources :users
```

And url for action show (profile): http://localhost:3000/users/1

I want change it with :role. For example:
http://localhost:3000/shops/1 (if User.role = 1)
or .../shippers/1 (if User.role = 0).

i don't know how to do that. Help me pls, Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails Routes based on condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230130/rails-routes-based-on-condition)

Comment: http://bjedrocha.com/rails/2015/03/18/role-based-routing-in-rails/ Please try this i think this can help you

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you'd be better using an [`enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) in your model. This way, you can assign actual roles to the `User.role` attribute (not just integers):

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: [:shipper, :shop]
end
```

This will still keep the `integer` in the database, but assign an actual name to the role in ActiveRecord. For example, you'll get `user.shipper?` and `user.shop?`.

---

Since I was interested to see a resolution, I looked online and found [this](http://minhajuddin.com/2011/10/24/how-to-change-the-rails-root-url-based-on-the-user-or-role/).

It explains what I had thought - you'll need to use a constraint to validate the role of the user and redirect accordingly. This way, you can send use a single route helper, and have the user sent to different routes depending on their role.

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230130/rails-routes-based-on-condition), I'd try something like:

```
# lib/role_constraint.rb
class RoleConstraint
  def initialize(*roles)
    @roles = roles
    @role  = request.env['warden'].user.try(:role)
  end

  def matches?(request)
    params = request.path_parameters
    @roles.include?(@role) && @role == params[:role]
  end
end


#config/routes.rb
resources :users, path: "", except: :show do
  get ":role/:id", action: :show, on: :collection, constraints: RoleConstraint.new([:shipper, :shop])
end
```

This isn't exactly what I'd want but it should create a single route, which is only accessible by the User with a role either as shipper or shop.

Comment: You'll need to add the lib dir to your autoload paths http://stackoverflow.com/a/19650564/1143732

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to map that route you can do

```
match '/shops/1', to: 'users#show'
match '/shippers/1', to: 'users#show'
```

This way you are processing that route with the show controller under the User structure. Then, the html of `/shops/1` should still be under `views/users/show` as rails will look for the view with the same name as the controller to render the page.

[UPDATE]

Then, in your controller you can say

```
<% if User.role == 1 %>
    <%redirect_to show_user_path%>
```