# How can I root to a nested model's new action which requires a param variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, root

Company belongs_to Users and a Company has_many Quotes. If a User is logged_in, and has a company created in the db, I would like to root to Quotes#new, which requires the company_id to be passed in. I can't seem to pass an argument into the root call, could you advise how I could achieve, a) a conditional root based upon logged in status and b) routing to a nested controller that requires parent id to be passed.

both:

```
root 'quotes#new', company_id: company.id
```

and:

```
root 'quotes#new', current_user
```

result in  `Couldn't find Company with 'id'=`

Thanks.

Info I'm finding to help me with this:

http://minhajuddin.com/2011/10/24/how-to-change-the-rails-root-url-based-on-the-user-or-role/

[Rails Routes based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230130/rails-routes-based-on-condition)

http://bjedrocha.com/rails/2015/03/18/role-based-routing-in-rails/

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/constrain-yourself

Comment: Any particular reason why this should be done in routes? Why not in a controller and redirect from there?

Comment: Are you using Devise?

Comment: No reason why it can't be done in a controller. I am using Devise.

Comment: You can't use `root` like that, by definition there are no parameters in the path. If a company has many quotes then it's usually a nested `resources` structure you define in your routes.

Comment: Getting a better grip on what i need to do now i think guys, root to a custom controller, perhaps Homepage, which runs a method to determine whether there's a devise logged in user, if true go here, if false go there. Slowly piecing together how to write it.