# Ruby Conditional Statement Best Practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

Sorry for such a naive question but can someone let me know what is the ruby way of writing the below line of code

```
result.nil? ? false : !result
```

Comment: What is that line supposed to do?

Comment: this line is returning bool based on the value of the result

Comment: Right now, it returns `true` if `result` is `false`, and `false` otherwise – is that expected?

Comment: Yes, 
if result is true then return false,
if result is false then return true,
if result is nil then return false

Comment: I understand mapping `true` to `false` and vice-versa. But may I ask why you want to treat `nil` like `true`? In Ruby, `false` and `nil` are usually considered both "falsy" and everything else "truthy".

Comment: Actually here I am routing conditionally using [Routing Constraits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29136866/20386850) and my constrain is that if the request has `Hash A` and That hash has `field B` which then returns bool based on the value of `Hash.dig('A','B')` and if the request has nil `Hash A` then return false.

Comment: Have a look at [`Hash#fetch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Hash.html#fetch-method) which allows to pass a default value if a key is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74274349/ruby-conditional-statement-best-practice#comment131130076_74274349):

> - if result is `true` then return `false`
> - if result is `false` then return `true`
> - if result is `nil` then return `false`

you just need to check for `result == false`:

```
result = true
result == false #=> false

result = false
result == false #=> true

result = nil
result == false #=> false
```

Comment: Could also do `if result ...` as nil is also falsey